# Create a artificial primary key / artificial column inside an SELECT-Statement (Oracle database)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL statement that looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    x, AVG(y) AS z
FROM 
    table
UNPIVOT
    (y FOR x
       IN ("COLUMN1" AS 'A',
           "COLUMN1" AS 'B',
           "COLUMN2" AS 'C',
           "COLUMN3" AS 'D',
           "COLUMN4" AS 'E',
           "COLUMN5" AS 'F',
           "COLUMN6" AS 'G'))
GROUP BY 
    x;
```

Is there a possibility to create an artificial key for each line inside of the `SELECT` statement? I can't add the ID of the table, because then I would have to add it to the group by clause as well and the output would differ from the previous output...

Basically I need to add a unique numeric column to the output of my select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an Oracle server to test it on, but something like this should work:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) AS id_num,
    x, AVG(y) AS z
FROM 
    table
UNPIVOT
    (y FOR x
       IN ("COLUMN1" AS 'A',
           "COLUMN1" AS 'B',
           "COLUMN2" AS 'C',
           "COLUMN3" AS 'D',
           "COLUMN4" AS 'E',
           "COLUMN5" AS 'F',
           "COLUMN6" AS 'G'))
GROUP BY 
    x;
```